# a part of my div become hidden when i move her to the top

Tags: html, css, less

the issue is when i try to move the 3 boxes in the second line they goes under the firs line div's here is the code :

http://jsfiddle.net/hvvdvqdt/

HTML :

```
 <!-- first row  -->
        <secction class="rowOne">

            <div class="col ">
                <div class="block hours">
                    8h00
                </div>  
            </div>      

        <div class="col ">
            <div class="block hours noss">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col ">
            <div class="block hours noss">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col ">
            <div class="block hours noss">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        </secction> 

        <!-- end of first row -->




        <!-- segend row  -->

        <section class="rowTwoo">

        <div class="col ">
            <div class="block hours">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col pers">
            <div class="block hours noss">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col pers">
            <div class="block hours noss">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="col pers">
            <div class="block hours noss">
                8h00
            </div>  
        </div>

        </section>

        <!-- end of segend row  -->
```

CSS :

```
.block {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.col {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}


.hours {
height:60px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
font-weight:bold;
}

.rowTwoo {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}



.rowOne {
    .noss {
    height:30px;

    }
}

.rowTwoo {
    .pers {
        position: relative;
        bottom:30px;
        z-index: 9;
    }
}
```

.............................................................................................

Comment: I like the fact that you refer to your div with the feminine pronoun and I hope this becomes a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this type of situation, you have to mention

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

for every 4th element (In your situation, put the above code after the 4th .
Add CSS for that,

```
.clear{clear:both; height:0; overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: with the height:0 the div will be hidden !

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply... network problem.... check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hvvdvqdt/3/